# FireServer() Doesn't fire the remote event

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

i was making a script that changes a value when the player dies, i did it with remote events but it didn't work.
Local Script:

```
local plr = game:GetService('Players').LocalPlayer
wait(2)
local char = plr.Character
local humanoid = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

humanoid.Died:Connect(function(death)
    print('death')
    game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage').setPlayerInLobby:FireServer()
    print('fired')
end)
```

Server script:

```
rs.setPlayerInLobby.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr)
    print("works i guess?")
    plr.InLobby.Value = true
end)
```

It printed out "death" and "fired" but it didn't do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You never defined the `rs` variable in your server Script.

```lua
local rs = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
local plr = game:GetService('Players').LocalPlayer

local char = plr.Character
local humanoid = char:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
if plr.Character.Humanoid.Health == 0 then
  print("Bla bla")
end
```

So you can use it on a local script i guess